# Python reading Default gateway, subnet mask and DNS

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, dns

I want to get the Default gateway IP using python, as well as the subnet mask and the DNS (primary and secondary) if any.

I already have a way of finding the local IP using `socket`

```
IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

However, I can't find a way (with sockets or other libraries) to extract DNS, Subnet, and Gateway, the same way as I did to the IP.

I was looking in google, and couldn't seem to find a solution that will work on all computers and all networks.

> I want the solution to work on every pc and on every network. meaning I don't want a windows only solution, or a solution involving downloading out-source libraries (if it's possible to do without it)

thank's in advanced,